# Very slow performance with QtWebengine 5.7.1

Tags: c++, qt, arm, qtwebengine

I'm working with `qtwebengine 5.7.1` but I'm experiencing a very slow performance on arm `microcontroller`. Even if I tried to enable hardware acceleration using command line commands after eglfs instruction (i.e. `./myBrowser --platform eglfs` ...commands) :

```
--qt-flag ignore-gpu-blacklist --qt-flag enable-gpu-rasterization --qt-flag enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers --qt-flag num-raster-threads=4
```

Or :

```
QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--enable-gpu-rasterization;etc.." mybrowser
```

Nothing seems to change... Is there something I'm missing?I tried to execute some benchmark test on https://browserbench.org/MotionMark/ but I receive always the same result.
At last but not least how can I open `chrome://gpu'` page on webengine? Why I'm not able to open any settings page even if I tried to open `'chromium://gpu'`?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot open any settings pages because these belong to the Chromium/Chrome browser application, not the underlying WebEngine.

First things first: have you tried with Qt 5.11? It comes with a more up to date Chromium codebase, which may influence performance.

Second, how are you sure it's performing slowly? Do you have measurements on similar software (i.e. another browser) to ensure that claim does not just reduce to "the microcontroller is not powerful enough to run a full-fledged browser"? You could even try a chrome/chromium build for that microcontroller and see how it performs directly (then you can access its configuration and check if it actually makes any difference). If Chromium/Chrome itself performs much better, this is a Qt(WebEngine) bug, and warrants fixing I would think. Contact Qt in this case.

If these options don't help, I'd contact either the Chrome/Chromium devs to see if anything can be done, or ask Qt (although if the problem lies in the Chrome webengine code, Qt devs will only be able to help a tiny bit).

Comment: I am having the same issue with Qt 5.11 when i try to load a page it is ridiculously slow, and some webpages report that my browser is out of date.

Comment: @rafael You could get rid of the update reports by setting another user agent (I believe), but the slow loading is problematic. I do hope this is a release/optimised build you're testing, and not a debug build. I would still strongly suggest to try Chromium proper on your chip and see if that suffers the same problem. If that is the case, you need to either have that fixed or look for another solution altogether.